# Word Count List with Extra

Tags: python

I am new to programming and attempting to create a program that reads a text file (A passage from Moby Dick), get rid of any marks that are not part of a traditional word i.e. '!','"','.','?', etc., make the word lowercase, remove any words that are in another text file called 'NewSet', and then print all of the remaining words with their word counts. I've been able to get the word count, but am having trouble removing those marks and eliminating any words that are in that separate list. If any more information is needed, please let me know and I can edit this post with it. Thank you! :)

```
file=open("Moby Dick.txt","r+")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in NewSet:
        for word in file.read().split():
            if word not in wordcount:
                wordcount[word] = 1
            else:
                wordcount[word] += 1

for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print(k,v)
file.close();
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Use a context manager to handle file objects, it's much better. Also, you're reading the entire file over and over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is answering to your question... How about just make another list to append *not eliminated* words?

```
file=open("Moby Dick.txt","r+")
wordcount={}
out = []
for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in NewSet:
        out.append(word)
        for word in file.read().split():
            if word not in wordcount:
                wordcount[word] = 1
            else:
                wordcount[word] += 1

for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print(k,v)
file.close()
print(out)
```

And you can write. (You can also use "with... as" style to open file.)

```
with open("new_text.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Hope this help.